# What does 裏頭 mean? Please comment on the usages containing 「裏頭」

Tags: meaning

From DeFrancis' Beginning Chinese Reader p. 208 – Lesson 20, Exercise 3, Items 3 and 10, I translated Lesson 20, Exercise 6, Item 11 into Chinese. Please confirm or refute the usage of 裏頭:

3. 從一九六二年以來他對**中國語言裏頭的外來語**很有研究.

   (Since 1962 he's done a lot of research on **loan words in Chinese**.)

10 **中英字典裏頭**沒有比這本好的了.

(**Among Chinese-English dictionaries** there is none better than this one.)

11. **Of those who do research on Chinese dialects,** the best is, I think, Association President Zhang. **⮕** **研究中國方言的人裏頭**，我認為最好的是張會長。

Comment: At least look it up in a dictionary first

Comment: 裏頭 = 裏面 = inside (of).

Answer (score 1):

裏頭 = inside; within

> 中國語言(裏頭)的外來語 - loan words (in) Chinese

you can replace "in" with "within' (中國語言 as a system)

> 中英字典(裏頭) - Among Chinese-English dictionaries

you can replace "among" with "within" (中英字典 as a category)

> 研究中國方言的人(裏頭) - (Of) those who do research on Chinese dialects

you can replace "of" with "within" (language researchers as a group)